# htaccess redirect infinite redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess RewriteRule that displays the url `auth/register.php` as `/register` like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} register
RewriteRule ^register/?$ /auth/register.php [NC,L]
```

However, now when someone manually types in `auth/register.php`into the browser window, I need to make sure they see `/register` instead. I was using

```
Redirect /auth/register.php /register
```

But obviously this creates an infinite redirect loop. Any ideas on how I can make it so any attempts to go to `/auth/register.php` go to `/register` but it still displays the contents of the `auth/register.php` without redirecting forever? Thanks!

Comment: I would start looking in `var_dump($_SERVER)` to find if there's any suitable properties you can apply logic against.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an Alias.

Here RewriteRule will always redirect you to the new url. So using that is making you to REDIRECT to `/auth/register.php` . Also you wrote one Redirection rule which is redirecting to `/register`. So this is an infinite loop of these two redirects.

Code that should be written is

```
Alias /register /auth/register.php
```

this should not be written in .htaccess file. It should be written in **Virtual host** file of your website

It looks similar to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /register /auth/register.php //Add this line only donot disturb any other lines


</VirtualHost>
```

In your .htaccess file **only include** this line

```
Redirect /auth/register.php /register
```

**Don't include**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} register
RewriteRule ^register/?$ /auth/register.php [NC,L]
```